# How to update ulimit value without restarting?

Tags: 16.04, server, ulimit

/etc/security/limits.conf

```
*         hard    nofile      500000
*         soft    nofile      500000
root      hard    nofile      500000
root      soft    nofile      500000
```

Ulimit -a is howing the following

```
 ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 127837
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 127837
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Ulimit is still showing only 1024

```
ulimit -n
1024


ulimit -Hn
1048576
ulimit -Sn
1024
```

How to set ulimit consistently ?